# Html template not rendering Vue content on screen

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Very lost on what can be causing this problem because it does not even work with copy/paste from the official website documentation!.

Trying only a "hello world" (app.js and index.html are in the same folder)

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>    
<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="my_view">
    {{ name }} {{ age }}
    </div>
    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the app.js content is:

```
var app = new Vue({ 
el: '#app',
data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
}});
```

And tried this way from a tutorial and not working either...

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
    template: '<h1>Hello World</h1>',
})

app.mount('#app')
```

I keep getting "   {{ message }}   " when I reload the page or nothing at all with the second method. Thanks.

Comment: I think you need a return statement in your `data: {...}`

Answer (score 2):

The example seems to work, just note that "name" and "age" must be inside app container `<div id="app"></div>` in this case

Try this basic example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>    
<body> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <div id="app">
        {{ message }}
        <p>
            {{ name }} {{ age }}
        </p>
    </div>
        <script>
    var app = new Vue({ 
      el: '#app',
      data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!',
        name: "ldonis",
        age: "30"
      }});
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can play a little with: https://jsfiddle.net/ldonis/g31Lstde/3/

Comment: Thanks, I could make that one work but when I put the content in the app.js file it stops working and shows {{ message }} {{ name }} {{ age }} strings.

Comment: Remember to load your javascript code at the end of the html